# Linq SQL Distinct at server side or app side?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need a Linq with distinct operation in C# app

SQL should be :

```
 select distinct(col1) from tableName;
```

I read some e.gs and know that i can write Linq like:

```
var myRes =
    (
         from a in tableName
         select a.col1
    ).Distinct();
```

So here is my question:

Does this linq :

get a  **whole set of** col1 from the MSSQL server to the myRes, 
then use C# distinct() function to make distinct  at my app side?

if it does so ,
can i make it distincted at the server side?

Or it does:

only get the **distincted** col1 from the MSSQL server, 
and nothing to do at my app side?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most ORM's will perform the `DISTINCT` on the SQL server side. What ORM are you using?

Comment: The easiest way is to find out is to run a trace with SQL Profiler, execute your code, and look at the actual SQL being sent to SQL Server.

Comment: Check SQL Profiler while running the query. Also try a different query with `distinct` inline inside of query.

Answer (score 4):

This should be performing the `DISTINCT` filter at the database side, unless something else is making the query execute before the filter is applied.  You can confirm this by running SQL Server Profiler when the query executes.

The way this works is by using [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx).  That is, the query doesn't actually run against the database until it needs to.  Prior to that, it builds up what's called an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) which then gets evaluated against the data source.  So you can append more and more `IQueryable<T>` extension methods on that statement, and they should all translate into a single query against the database.

What you're passing around in this case (`myRes`) isn't really the result set, it's a reference to the query which will create the result set.  The query gets built and evaluated when the enumeration is evaluated into an actual result set.  Such as when you call:

- `.ToList()`
- `.Single()`
- `.SingleOrDefault()`
- `.First()`
- `.FirstOrDefault()`
- etc.

Basically anything that takes a reference to a query and turns it into an actual value or collection of values.

Comment: You mean IQueryable<T> extension methods.  Once you end up with an IEnumerable<T> you are going to trigger the sql query.

Comment: @drch: Well, sort of.  But I see your point.  An `IEnumerable<T>` that's a result of a `yield return` isn't executed until it's enumerated, so it's still just a reference to a potential result.